# How do I create a USB networking interface for passing internet to my Android phone?

Tags: networking, usb, android

I am working on passing through the internet from my computer to my phone (running Android) over USB.  I'm not sure how to achieve this, but I know I will need a usb network interface, such as `usb0`.  This interface is not automatically created when plugging in the phone.

How do I create this USB network interface?  Can this be done within Linux or must it be done from the Android phone?

**Note:**  If I enable USB tethering on the phone, then a corresponding USB interface is created in Linux.  However this is automatically configured to use the phone as a network device (or a gateway?) and pass the internet from my phone to my computer, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you done with this thing? Please, I was eagerly waiting for something like this in Linux/Unix! Please respond.

Comment: @shekharsuman Unfortunately, I was never able to get this to work and have given up on it.

Comment: @drs-Nevertheless, you tried at least such an awesome concept. You've provided me a very good project to work on. Really thanks. I'll start working on this coming June. THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 4):

Actually USB tethering creates a symmetric connection between your phone and PC. The direction your traffic can go is only defined by the network interface configuration and the services running on each side.

In order to let the traffic go from the phone to the PC, you could (for example):

- configure your PC to run DHCP and share its internet connection
- activate USB tethering on your android phone:
- run a dhcp client on your android phone (as root):

`netcfg usb0 dhcp`

Or

`dhclient usb0`

Different phones may have different names for the interface, including `rndis0`, `rmnet0` etc. Those can be discovered via `ifconfig`.

In case of problems, it may also be worth a try to load the `g_ether` kernel module on your phone manually.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can share with you my experience:

On the phone (Samsung J1 (Android 5.1.1) **rooted**):
Active *Developer Options* >> Active *USB Debugging* >> I am going to *Anchorage to network and Portable and active zone Anchorage* (sorry for the translation, I'm from Cuba) to *USB network* >> When I do this I open the Virtual Terminal emulator (an apk) and I access as **root** (`su`) and I check the network interfaces with `ifconfig` , which returns a "new" interface called **rndis0** and with **IP 192.168.42.129**

On the PC with Debian:
I open the terminal and I access as **root** (only to not have to be putting `sudo` every time) >> `ifconfig` and it returns a "new" interface called **usb0** with **IP 192.168.42.111**

If you ping from the phone to the PC and vice versa and everything should be ok (I get answers in the two sides), now it's time to give the phone a gateway, so in the terminal emulator from the phone:
`route add default gw 192.168.42.111 dev rndis0` >> putting here the IP of the PC
At this point you should be able to ping the Google DNS (both by IP and by name) from the terminal emulator and if your internet connection doesn't need a proxy server configuration you have internet in your phone via USB cable...

PS: If your PC and phone don't take IP automatically use this:

On PC:

```
ifconfig usb0 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

On phone:

```
ifconfig rndis0 10.42.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
busybox route add default gw 10.42.0.1 dev rndis0
```

And configure the DNS (still phone):

```
mount -o remount, rw /system
echo 'nameserver 192.168.6.40' > /system/etc/resolv.conf
mount -o remount, ro /system
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT 1 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.6.40:53
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 8.0

```
ifconfig usb0 192.168.225.3 netmask 255.255.255.0
ndc network create 9792
ndc network interface add 9792 usb0
ndc network route add 9792 usb0 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.225.1
ndc resolver setnetdns 9792 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
ndc network default set 9792
```