# archlinux share laptop internet from wifi to mobile connected via USB. Its also know as reverse tethering

Tags: android, wifi-hotspot

I have a laptop with internet getting from wifi.

I want to provide internet to my android mobile which is connected by USB cable.

I know i can create a wifi hotspot on my laptop using create_ap program  can connect. If i do that i miss internet on my laptop and the whole purpose is lost. Because my wifi in laptop does not allow simulataneous wifi and ap.

Any help in this regard is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your android support USB ethernet (rndis), you can check [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90020/how-do-i-create-a-usb-networking-interface-for-passing-internet-to-my-android-ph). Read k.Cyborg's answer.

That will establish virtual ethernet via USB between phone and laptop.

On laptop you can use script [linux-router](https://github.com/garywill/linux-router) to easily server dhcp and nat forward.